# How to gzip 100 GB files faster with high compression

Tags: performance, gzip

We have 100+ GB files on a Linux machine, and while trying to perform gzip using below command, gzip is taking minimum 1-2 hours to complete:

```
gzip file.txt
```

Is there a way we can make gzip to run fast with the same level of compression happening when we use gzip?

---

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M CPU @2.30 GHz

Comment: With the bandwidth available to me in my Fiber@Home connection, sending 100 Gb over the internet would've only taken me 2-3 hours. What exactly are your goals? A compressed archive of this size is nearly useless, since accessing the content implies unzipping the entire thing. You may want to re-think your use case and maybe just buy a bigger hard drive.

Comment: Are you limited to gzip?  If not, parallel bzip2 (`pbzip2`) and parallel xz (`xz --threads`) exist.

Comment: @RonJohn .. Thanks ron. But we dont have this library in Linux. What is meant by xz --threads ?

Comment: Does [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/872749/bzip2-too-slow-multiple-cores-are-avaible) help you?

Comment: @Ravi `xz --threads` means to use the `xz` command with the `--threads` parameter to paralellize the processing.

Comment: Note that if you are using a single hard disk drive (as opposed to SSDs or RAID setups), the I/O alone will probably take a significant part of the time, so even parallelising may not gain that much.

Comment: @jcaron there's always a sweet spot that saturates IO while using as much CPU as possible.  (Not that I think that's wise on systems doing more than just compressing that file...)

Comment: Also since there are multiple files, it’s easy to run gzip on each file simultaneously. But I don’t expect a large gain in performance doing them in parallel compared to doing them in sequence.

Comment: @MartijnHeemels ..Can you help me with complete syntax of using --threads

Comment: @Ravi do you know how to use options when running programs?  Do you know how to read `man` pages?

Comment: @Ravi It looks like [parallel bzip is available for Ubuntu 20.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/pbzip2/filelist). I'm not sure if it's available for older systems.

Comment: While compressing, what is your CPU usage, your disk usage, and your memory usage? Those are very very important to the answers.

Comment: @jcaron: Kernel readahead into pagecache overlaps disk with compression, so the only time when a core won't be working on single-threaded gzip is while the kernel basically does memcpy from pagecache into userspace (inside a `read` system call).  A single gzip thread is slower than sequential read even on old rotational media. On 3.9GHz Skylake i7-6700k compressing text (an old Linux kernel git source tree, including incompressible git pack), `gzip` only manages to read 37MiB/s of uncompressed tar input on average, reading the `.tar` from tmpfs (and output about half that).

Comment: (An earlier comment had bad numbers; `tar` reading from NFS was the bottleneck in my first test).

Comment: The OP can expect a linear speedup from 2 threads on that old Sandybridge laptop CPU.  On my system, `pigz -p4` hits 139MiB (1 thread per core), while `pigz` using all 8 threads hits 158MiB/s input-read, with an average utilization of 5.978 logical CPU cores over 5.5 seconds.  Arch Linux.  (So on SKL, hyperthreading gave a speedup of 13% over single-thread: more competition for the same cache, but the branch miss rate is high enough that HT does help more than it hurts keeping execution units fed with work).

Comment: @jcaron: The OP's i3 mobile is an older microarchitecture, and only has 2c4t at ~60% the clock speed so the actual throughput would be ~46MiB/s for a 2c4t SKL @ 2.3GHz.  Accounting for microarchitectural speedups in SKL vs. SnB (and ignoring RAM speed differences), maybe another 30%, so maybe 35MiB/s, certainly in that ballpark to within a factor of 2. vs. a slow 1TB desktop disk from 10 years ago (WD10EACS green power 5400rpm) having sequential read of over 90 to 60MiB/s (start / end of disk) or something like that. So with both cores maxed out, they might approach I/O bottleneck on slow rust

Comment: @jpaugh: bzip2 is usually a poor choice for most use-cases, vs. gzip or LZMA (xz).  It's slower than gzip to compress, and importantly *much* slower to decompress, IIRC, even than LZMA.  As commenters point out, giant compressed archives are going to be nasty to get anything out of, so decompression speed may be a major concern.  (`7z` to make zip-like archives with an index can be good.  "Solid" archives can take advantage of redundancy between files, while still using a reasonable block size so you don't have to decompress too much unwanted data to get to what you do want.)

Comment: @PeterCordes At this point, gzip is arguably a poor choice anymore for most use cases as well, as you have better options for fast compression (LZ4, LZO, snappy, brotli), good compression (xz, 7zip), or both (zstandard). The only reason to choose gzip today is compatibility, and possibly if you’®e dealing with an embedded device that has a hardware implementation of the DEFLATE algorithm.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: Oh wow, I didn't know gzip no longer had a niche where it was a good speed/space tradeoff.  I knew about lz4 and LZO, and LZMA, but hadn't realized that zstd could compress as well as gzip but much faster.  I'd heard of it but hadn't played with it yet.

Comment: @PeterCordes Brotli can, under certain circumstances, actually outperform gzip in both space and speed as well. It’s a lot less general than zstandard is however, only really doing well for highly structured text (but it beats most other compression hands down in that particular niche, as it was designed specifically for near real-time streaming compression of highly structured test).

Comment: Have you positively identified the bottleneck in the current procedure?

Comment: While it is good to find a drop-in replacement for your workflow (parallel tools, other compression algorithm or level) you could also think about changing the storage format into split up archives. This has a number of advantages: naturally allows parallle transfer and compression, does not require to have double the space for compress and uncompress. Makes transmission restarts easier since failures only impact smaller chunks and allows partial interim protection and encryption&Is compat with older infrastructure like blob storage, backup and mobile filesystems which might have a 2-5GB lim

Comment: @RonJohn: `zstdmt --adapt` aims to hit that sweet spot that saturates I/O and CPU, adapting on the fly (within a set range) to "perceived I/O conditions".  [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/zstd/zstdmt.1.en.html).  IDK if `--adapt` is usable with `--format=gzip`, to take advantage of that and zstd's threaded I/O (and compression) for the `.gz` format.

Answer (score 31):

If you are using gzip, you use mostly one processor core (well, some parts of the task, like reading and writing data are kernel tasks and kernel will use another core). Have a look at some multicore-capable gzip replacements, e.g. MiGz (https://github.com/linkedin/migz) or Pigz (https://zlib.net/pigz/, for some longer explanation see also e.g. https://medium.com/ngs-sh/pigz-a-faster-alternative-to-gzip-for-big-files-d5909e46d659).

Comment: Since you have multiple files you could instead gzip more than one at the same time

Comment: `pigz` is pretty universally available. Try to install it with your package manager of choice.

Comment: `pigz` is probably already installed on your system.

Comment: @MichaelHampton .. I ran man command but i cant see this available -- No manual entry for pigz

Comment: man is just a man page. `which pigz` would be a bit more related to a command availability...

Comment: in case one looks next to parallel bzip (for possible better compression ratios depending on the data), there are both pbzip2 and lbzip2, be aware that these use competing parallel-bzip formats, and compressing with in parallel one will not necessarily decompress with the other in parallel

Answer (score 20):

> We have 100+ GB files and while trying to perform gzip using below command , gzip is taking minimum 1-2 hours to get complete

With CPU (taken from a comment): [Intel® Core™ i3-2350M @ 2.30GHz](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/53438/intel-core-i3-2350m-processor-3m-cache-2-30-ghz.html), which has:

Number of Cores: 2; **Number of Threads: 4**

---

Your CPU sounds like a bottleneck according to [this low score](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel%20Core%20i3-2350M%20%40%202.30GHz&id=758) (benchmark), also to note this is a laptop CPU, quite an old one. In this setup, I expect a classic HDD instead of some modern SSD too, together with possibly low RAM, etc.

---

The conclusion is possibly no, you cannot do software-wise anything to get the higher performance of `gzip` on your computer without getting a lower compression ratio, of course.

---

Default compression setting is `-6` if I am not mistaken, **you could hit for example `-2`**:

```
gzip -2 file.txt
```

and compare the results yourself. See the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip) for more settings.

---

### UPDATE on `pigz`

Today, 2021-Jun-03, I myself needed to compress a rather large file of size 256 GB (**239 GiB**), and I somewhat tested `gzip`, `bzip2`, `xz`, and I found all of these being unable to take full advantage of my CPU ([i7-7700HQ](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97185/intel-core-i7-7700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html)) and being fast, which is our goal in this Q&A.

In the end, I downloaded `pigz` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pigz)) from its [home page](https://zlib.net/pigz/), and compiled it simply by running `make`, then as I did not prefer to directly put it onto my `PATH`, so I created a Bash alias to the binary.

It might be useful to note how to watch the (possibly long) progress:

Example #1 (reading a prepared disk image and writing `gzip`'ed file in the same directory):

```sh
file=disk.img; pv < "$file" | pigz -2 > "$file".gz
```

Example #2 (reading disk directly and writing `gzip`'ed file in the the current directory):

```sh
dev=/dev/nvme0n1; file=disk.img.gz; pv < "$dev" | pigz -9 > "$file"
```

---

### Conclusion

I now recommend using `pigz`, the **p**arallel **i**mplementation of **gz**ip, on very large files.

Comment: Regarding the 2021-Jun-03 update - have you tried `xz -T0` to utilize all CPU cores?

Comment: @orip Yes, I did. However, only a small portion of the _normal_ `xz` is able to utilize all threads. + It is painfully slow, h*ll, extremely slow, depending on settings; `pixz` would be of more service [(man page)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pixz.1.html)

Answer (score 9):

Do you specifically need gzip, or would other compression algorithms be an option? zstandard and lzop are both significantly faster than gzip.

Comment: `lz4` has a somewhat better tradeoff of compression ratio to performance than lzop.  (both are about the same speed at `-2`, but lzop makes a slightly smaller file.)  It's used for stuff like transparent filesystem compression in btrfs.  But don't turn up the compression ratio unless you need the blazing fast decompression: if you don't need the blazing fast *decompression* of lzop or lz4, `lz4 -4` is *much* slower, similar to `gzip -4` which compresses somewhat better.  And `pigz -4` for parallel gzip lets you use both cores for a 2x speedup.  (`lzop -4` or `-6` doesn't improve like lz4 does)

Comment: @PeterCordes btw btrfs has switched from lzo to zstandard by default

Comment: https://community.centminmod.com/threads/round-3-compression-comparison-benchmarks-zstd-vs-brotli-vs-pigz-vs-bzip2-vs-xz-etc.17259/ benchmarks compression speed and size on a Haswell quad-core for various compressors, including `pigz` vs. `zstd` vs. parallel bzip2 vs. parallel lzma.  No lz4 or lzop in that test, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes I found that `lzop` was great when I needed to migrate an on-prem Oracle database to AWS Postgres.

Answer (score 8):

As the others have pointed out, `gzip` is single-threaded.

If you have multiple files to process, you could do that in parallel:

```
find -type f -not -name '*.gz' -print0 | xargs -tr0n 1 -P$(nproc) gzip
```

- `find`: scan the file system tree
- `-type f`: filter for regular files
- `-not`: invert the next test

  - `-name '*.gz'`: any files that are already compressed
- `print0`: print the name to stdout, followed by a NUL byte
- `|` pipe into
- `xargs`: read elements from stdin, and pass them as arguments to another program
- `-t`: write the commands run to the console
- `-r`: do not execute any command if no elements are present
- `-0`: expect elements to be separated by NUL bytes
- `-n 1`: give one element to each invocation
- `-P ...`: run as many commands in parallel

  - `$(...)`: run this command and substitute its output

    - `nproc`: get the number of processors
- `gzip`: the command to be run for each file

Note that gzip is still rather fast as an algorithm, so you are likely to be I/O bound in this, and at the same time the compression isn't that great. If you are free to choose another compression method, you can use `xz` instead, which compresses way better, but needs more CPU time for that.

In theory, `xz` can parallelize internally, but that gives slightly worse compression:

```
xz -T$(nproc) *.txt
```

Comment: compressing files separately will result in worse compression ratio because you can't have solid archives anymore

Comment: The CPU doesn't care if you launch 4 instances of gzip, **but the disk sure does**.  Compressing >1 files at once will cause a lot of disk thrash as the heads have to constantly hop among all the different files being concurrently read (on top of those being written).  That, then, is likely to become your bottleneck!  (having benchmarked that very thing in the past).  We can guess if OP has a CPU like that, then whatever is being used to handle multiple 100GB fies, is not a terabyte-class SSD.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I've executed this in a 32-cores server with SSD disks. It was 283 files ~800MB each. Took a couple minutes and worked great.

Answer (score 4):

Your bottlenecks are: how fast it can read the file, how fast it can compress it, and how fast it can write it or transfer it to the destination media, perhaps over the network.

First thing to do would be to run the gzip command while monitoring the output of

```
vmstat 1
```

in another terminal. You'll see if your CPU is maxed out, how many cores it uses, and how much MB/s it reads and writes. Also monitor vmstat while copying a huge file to get an idea of your hard drive's max read/write speed. Then you'll know if the operation is cpu bound or io bound.

You can also use

```
time gzip ...
```

It will tell you how much cpu time it used versus the total time, so that gives useful hints on whether it's cpu bound or waiting for IO.

If you intend to transfer the compressed file to another harddisk or over the network, then it makes sense to do so while compressing it, instead of using a separate copy operation. If the destination drive is local, just use the adequate gzip syntax ; if it is remote you can use a network share or:

```
gzip -c file.txt | ssh user@ip "cat > destfile.gz"
```

This will gzip the file and transfer it in one pipelined operation, which is faster than two separate steps.

Now, watch vmstat and determine if the operation is io-bound, network-bound, or cpu-bound. I recommend to install the utility "pv" and use it like this:

```
gzip -c file.txt | pv | ssh user@ip "cat > destfile.gz"
```

pv will display how many MB/s of compressed data is transferred through the network. You can test your HDD read, network, and write on the other end with this:

```
cat file.txt | pv | ssh user@ip "cat > destfile.gz"
```

You can test your HDD network and write on the other end with this:

```
cat /dev/zero | pv | ssh user@ip "cat > destfile.gz"
```

...and you can test only the network with this:

```
cat /dev/zero | pv | ssh user@ip "cat > /dev/null"
```

Now you should have a much better idea of what slows it down. Note if you use samba network shares you should also test the throughput:

```
cat /dev/zero | pv > /mnt/share/filename
```

...just in case your network share performance is clobbered by a misconfiguration, it's always nice to know.

If you determine that the problem is really gzip's speed, then the solution is to use a faster multithreaded compressor like zstandard. You can also use a faster compression setting, since saving a few GB of harddisk space is probably much less important than saving a few hours.

If compressed file size is less important than how long it takes, the optimum solution is a compression that is fast enough to saturate either the disk or network bottleneck.

For example if you have a slow network and a fast disk, and you have cpu to spare, using a higher compression setting will make it faster by transferring a smaller amount of compressed data. But if you have a fast network and a slow CPU, then a lower compression setting will use less CPU so it will be faster.

Now, where does this 100GB file comes from? This is not a common file size... and it hints that you should really be using rsync in delta mode.

Answer (score 3):

Your storage is slowing you down.

```
gzip file.txt
```

Assuming file.txt is 100GB like you said, this requires reading 100GB from file.txt and writing somewhat less to file.txt.gz in the same directory.

If you have a spinning drive, that's a lot of head thrashing. If you have an SSD, it still only handles one read OR write at a time.

```
gzip -c file.txt > /mount/some_other_drive/file.txt.gz
```

The source drive can now deliver a steady stream of data, the destination drive can write the results without stopping every so many blocks to read the original file.

The destination must of course be on a different physical volume, and preferably a different interface to the computer.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to say it's the storage. Depending on compression settings, lower end CPUs could be a bottleneck.

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen lower-end cpu *could* be the issue. Trying to read-write 150GB to the same directory *will* be slower than splitting the read and write between devices. There is no single bottleneck here, it's a + b + c.

Comment: I estimated ([in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623881/how-to-gzip-100-gb-files-faster-with-high-compression/624056?noredirect=1#comment1167421_623881)) that the OP's CPU, using both cores (`pigz`), can probably average about 35MiB/s input compressing text.  35MiB/s sequential read + maybe 10 to 12MiB/s sequential write is likely something a rotational disk of similar vintage can handle, with the kernel doing readahead and write buffering to overlap actual DMA with `pigz` in user-space.  So most read and write syscalls won't block, especially not with a single thread.

Comment: This would be useful if using a much faster compressor like `zstdmt` (multi-threaded zstdandard); rotational drives do much better with pure sequential read than with mixed read and write to separate locations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at likely usage of the compressed file.

If its unlikely to need uncompressing, e.g. its a compressed version of a backup file, choose a compression method that is fast to compress but can be slow to decompress. gzip is not the only compression program.

If you expect to commonly uncompress the file, then is the work done to compress/decompress actually worth doing?

In addition, many large files do not compress particularly well - for example video, sound, graphics and some databases could be considered virtually incompressible. It is worth finding out how much compression actually 'saves'.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure whether you are bottlenecked by the CPU of by I/O.
If by I/O, the only way to improve, is to read from one and write to another drive, if available.
Your CPU is quite weak, I see little point trying any modern compression algorithm, as those are generally more CPU-intensive.
As your CPU has two cores, you can divide the file into two parts and gzip them in parallel. When done, you can concatenate these two gz files back into one (this is a neat feature of gzip format). Assumption here is that you have enough I/O.
You may also play around with gzip compression levels down to 1.